# Node WriteFile not writing objects I need using underscore. Writes the whole objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, underscore.js

I'm trying to select only certain values from my object to write into a file. But this writes the whole object and also unless I use util.inspect it just writes as objects. This should write the values I have chosen from the objects line by line as they come in:

```
var objectsToFile = function(objectsTotal){

    objectsTotal = _.values(objectsTotal, function(value) {
        return value.objectTo.employeeName;
    });

    objectsTotal = _.values(objectsTotal, function(value) {
        return value.employeeCurrent;
    });

    objectsTotal = _.values(objectsTotal, function(value) {
        return value.employeePast;
    });



        writeFile('objectsTotalet.csv', util.inspect(objectsTotal), function(err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
};
```

objectsTotal comes through the function like:

```
[ { objectTo:                        
 { employeeName: 'John',         
   employeeID: '234234', 
   DOB: '2333'},         
employeeCurrent: true,
employeePast: false},  
{ objectTo:                        
 { employeeName: 'Janet',         
   employeeID: '23423432', 
   DOB: '23333' },        
employeeCurrent:true,
employeePast: false} ]
```

The output will be conditional which is why I'm using the underscore library but it doesn't work it doesn't even use the returned values from underscore:

There will be other values added to the object so will also need to add a return value like:

```
objectsTotal = _.values(objectsTotal, function(value) {
        return value.employeeStatus != 'employed' ||
        value.url.indexOf('employee:') === -1 ||
        value.employeeid.length === ('id:')
});
```

I do need to use this library to give the results I want in a csv file. The output will look like the objectsTotal values returned line by line and can be in one cell.

Comment: Why do you insist on using underscore?

Comment: @chsdk The code is already written in my other application that doesn't use node, if you can provide an answer that works the same way with the last condition too I will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your underscore code doesn't seem to work because it doesn't return any result in your `_.values()` calls.

I think you are mis-using the `_.values()` method from the [**`_.values()` underscore Docs**](http://underscorejs.org/#values) we can see that it doesn't have a second argument for a `callback`, so I think the code in this callback will never be executed.

**Solution:**

Anyway this can be achieved with pure JavaScript code:

```
var filteredObjects = objectsTotal.filter(function(value) {
  return value.objectTo.employeeStatus != 'employed';
}).map(function(obj) {
  return {
    employeeName: obj.objectTo.employeeName,
    employeeCurrent: obj.employeeCurrent,
    employeePast: obj.employeePast
  }
}).map(function(o) {
  return Object.values(o);
});
```

**Explanation:**

- We use **[`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method to filter the objects having the specified conditions, I used only one test but you can implement all your tests, it will give us an `array` with all the objects matching these conditions.
- Then we use **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method to get only `employeeName`, `employeeCurrent` and `employeePast` properties of each `object`.
- Then we recall **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to get only the values of these propeties using **[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)** in the callback function.

After filtering your `array` of objects, you can transform it to a `string` using **[`.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b)** like this:

```
var filteredResult = filteredObjects.reduce(function(acc, currentValue) {
    return accumulator + currentValue.join(" \n");
}).join(" ,");
```

Then write the content of `filteredResult` string variable to your `csv` file:

```
writeFile('objectsTotalet.csv', filteredResult, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var objectsTotal = [{
    objectTo: {
      employeeName: 'John',
      employeeID: '234234',
      DOB: '2333',
      employeeStatus: 'employed'
    },
    employeeCurrent: true,
    employeePast: false
  },
  {
    objectTo: {
      employeeName: 'Janet',
      employeeID: '23423432',
      DOB: '23333',
      employeeStatus: 'unemployed'
    },
    employeeCurrent: true,
    employeePast: false

  }
];

var filteredObjects = objectsTotal.filter(function(value) {
  return value.objectTo.employeeStatus != 'employed';
}).map(function(obj) {
  return {
    employeeName: obj.objectTo.employeeName,
    employeeCurrent: obj.employeeCurrent,
    employeePast: obj.employeePast
  }
}).map(function(o) {
  return Object.values(o);
});

var filteredResult = filteredObjects.reduce(function(acc, currentValue) {
    return accumulator + currentValue.join(" \n");
}).join(" ,");

console.log(filteredResult);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script data-require="lodash.js@*" data-semver="4.17.4" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this how would you create and write to the file and also do you have any idea why my code isn't working? Also there will be a lot of objects coming through and each set needs to be on a new line sorry.

Comment: @Sam your code doesn't return anything, I think the problem comes from the conditions you are using for example the last one `value.employeeid.length === ('id:')` will be always `false` because you are trying to compare a string to a number.

Comment: This works, thanks alot. Only one problem left it's including the brackets [[ and also the quotes ', how can I get rid of these? With my code even in the first return statement if I do a console.log this never gets printed do you know why?

Comment: @Sam I think you are mis-using the `_.values()`method from the [`._values()` **underscore Docs**](http://underscorejs.org/#values) we can see that it doesn't have a second argument for a callback, so I think the code in this callback will never be executed.

Comment: @Sam I edited the answer to make it write the results as a string, ommitting the double `[[]]`.

Comment: It works without the filtered results if I do filteredObjects.join("/n"). Takes out the brackets too, weird (maybe utils was bringing them in). But thanks

Comment: @Sam Yes it will, because CSV is a comma-separated structure file like an array, so that's why `filteredObjects.join("/n")` will work as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I realized what you want to achieve in a plunker using lodash with a chain of multiple functions, this is the code used :

```
// First, do your filtering conditions here
var game = data.filter(g => {
   return g.debit === true; 
});

// Then, pick the wanted attributes here
game = _.map(game, (g) => {
    var o = _.pick(g, ['amount', 'debit']);
    o = Object.values(o);
    return o;
});

// Finally merge your arrays here
var merged = [].concat.apply([], game);
```

For printing your array into csv, you just have to use the final merge array in your printing function.

Here's the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/uvH4Ww4HMaQQVXQCBVKP

I hope that I answered your question as needed.

PS: I can explain every block of code which isn't clear.

Comment: But how would I achieve the last condition where I return based on OR conditions. I would just like to know why the code above isn't working correctly. It works correctly if I don't use node in my other application so I know it is achievable

Comment: You should make your conditions in the first filter function.

Comment: Okay thanks can you replace the variables with what I have used and return the same output, I'm giving 150 points and need to see if your code will work :)? And explain why it doesnt work the way I have done it, it doesn't even get into the _ functions.